# How to replace pointers with references in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

"I am sure there are tens of questions with the same title. Many of them are duplicate. Mine might be duplicate too, but I couldn't find any. So I try to make it very neat, short and simple."

I have an hierarchy like this:

```
class Shape {
public:
   virtual void virtualfunc()  { std::cout << "In shape\n"; }
};

class Circle: public Shape {
public:
   void virtualfunc()  { std::cout << "In Circle\n"; };
};
```

and when I use the classes with the help of pointer, the functions are called as I expected:

```
int main() {
   Shape shape_instance;
   Shape* ref_shape = &shape_instance ;
   Circle circle_instance;
   Circle* ref_circle = &circle_instance;

   ref_shape = dynamic_cast<Shape*> (ref_circle);
   ref_shape->virtualfunc();
}
```

Here the program calls the `virtualfunc()` of the derived class and the result is naturally : `In Circle`

Now, I want to get rid of the pointers, use references instead, and get the same result. So I make trivial modifications to `main()` to look like this:

```
int main() {
   Shape shape_instance;
   Shape& ref_shape = shape_instance;
   Circle circle_instance;
   Circle& ref_circle = circle_instance;

   ref_shape = dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle);
   ref_shape.virtualfunc();
}
```

But this time, the program calls the `virtualfunc()` of the base class and the result is  : `In Shape`

I appreciate if you let me know which concept of the references I am missing and how to change the references in the main() to get the result I got in the pointer version.

thank you

Comment: Why did you declare ref_shape again at this line Shape& ref_shape = dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle);?

Comment: sorry, a typo. I will just edit that

Comment: There is no need to `dynamic_cast` to the base, that is an implicit conversion.

Comment: In short, I missed the concept that **references cannot be reassigned**!!!   thank you all

Answer (score 18, accepted):

References cannot be reseated. Once you initialize the reference in the initialization, it becomes an alias to the referred object and cannot be distinguished from it. The latter assignment:

```
ref_shape = dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle);
```

really means:

```
shape_instance = dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle);
```

You can, on the other hand, bind a new reference to the object (and you don't need the `dynamic_cast`, as the conversion from reference to derived to reference to base is implicit):

```
Shape & another_ref = ref_circle;
another_ref.virtualfunc();          // Dispatches to Circle::virtualfunc
```

Answer (score 6):

This is where your `Circle` is turning into a `Shape`.

```
ref_shape = dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle);
//        ^ here
ref_shape.virtualfunc();
```

`ref_shape` has already been defined to be a reference to `shape_instance`.

You are **not** copying the reference itself, since references cannot be reassigned.  You are copying the actual object to a `Shape` object.  It's getting stored in `shape_instance`.

You can verify this by trying this code.  It will print `In Circle`.

```
dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle).virtualfunc();
```

Comment: @rahman Note there is no need for `dynamic_cast` in your situation, if I correctly understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You should do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

 class Shape {
  public:
   virtual void virtualfunc()  { std::cout << "In shape\n"; }
 };

 class Circle: public Shape {
   public:
   void virtualfunc()  { std::cout << "In Circle\n"; };
 };

 int main() {
    Shape shape_instance;
    //Shape& ref_shape = shape_instance;
    Circle circle_instance;
    Circle& ref_circle = circle_instance;

    Shape& ref_shape = dynamic_cast<Shape&>(ref_circle);
    ref_shape.virtualfunc();
}
```

It outputs in Circle as you expected.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry again. i corrected the error. Kindly have a look. thanks

Comment: nice. But why? what I can see is that ref_shape calls the virtual function of the object that is 'first' assigned to it.is this a correct explaination?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve/show (i.e. dynamic virtual function binding), perhaps this code will help:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
  public:
    virtual void virtualfunc()  { std::cout << "In shape\n"; }
};

class Circle: public Shape {
  public:
    void virtualfunc()  { std::cout << "In Circle\n"; };
};

int main() {
  Circle circle_instance;

  // don't care what kind of Shape
  Shape &someShape = circle_instance;

  someShape.virtualfunc();
}
```

Here you can see that `someShape` can be bound to `Shape` or any derived class and the virtual function will be called on the actual **dynamic type**. This will print `In Circle`. Proof: http://ideone.com/A1UvrR

There's no need for `dynamic_cast`

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. I made the modification. please have a look. thanks

Comment: That is what confuses me. when I assign a circle(through dynamic cast), I expected to call the circle methods(as it does in the pointer version) why is this not hapening?